# Cannot Color GeoDataFrame points

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I want to plot locations across Paris and color them by the column type. I also want to plot a legend associated with the location types. I can create the GeoDataframe, plot the locations across Paris. However I cannot specify the color of the points on the map. Additionally I have to create a Legend separately and then apply it to the plot.

How do I get the colors of the plot points to match the legend columns?

[image]

code:

```
paris = gpd.read_file(shape_filepath)
ax = paris.plot(figsize=(40,10), linewidth=1, edgecolor='white', color='lightgrey')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title("Casino Banner Stores Paris", fontdict={"fontsize": "25","fontweight" : "5"})

xl = r"summary.xlsx"
df =pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name = "paris_stores_and_metro_chart")
df = df.dropna()

#Create Points for Shape file - these are long lat pairs
geometry =[Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["lng"],df["lat"])]
crs ={'init':'espg:4326'}
#Create GeoDataFrame
stores =gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs=crs,geometry=geometry)
stores.plot(ax=ax,figsize=(40,10), column=stores['colour'], cmap=None)


legend_elements =     [  
                        Line2D([0],[0], markerfacecolor ='#0000ff',marker='o', color='w',label ='casino'),
                        Line2D([0],[0], markerfacecolor ='#3366ff',marker='o', color='w', label ='fanrpix'),
                        Line2D([0],[0], markerfacecolor ='#00e6b8',marker='o',  color='w',label ='geant'),
                        Line2D([0],[0], markerfacecolor ='#e6e600',marker='o', color='w', label ='leader price'),
                        Line2D([0],[0], markerfacecolor ='#e65c00',marker='o', color='w', label ='metro station'),
                        Line2D([0],[0], markerfacecolor ='#ff00ff',marker='o', color='w', label ='monoprix'),
                        Line2D([0],[0], markerfacecolor ='#e60000',marker='o', color='w', label ='naturalia')
                    ]


ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, fontsize =20)
```

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your gdf, is hard to guess. But if you are passing colours directly, you have to pass them to `color` not `column`.

Comment: hi @martinfleis type|address|lat|lng|colour
casino 20 rue du chemin vert,75011,paris 48.8581032 2.3722275  #0000ff  is the structure. I have tried using color ('c') and I got an error when trying to supply more than one color - i passed it the colour column from the dataframe as a series. I tried using a colormap to get round this but then I could not map the colors to the legend.

Comment: Do not use `c` but `color` as I said above.

Comment: when I pass the "colour" column as the source for the color argument i get this 'color' kwarg must be an mpl color spec or sequence of color specs.
For a sequence of values to be color-mapped, use the 'c' argument instead.  I used c as color was not working, perhaps I am passing the series wrong?:                                                                         stores.plot(ax=ax,figsize=(40,10), color=stores['colour'], cmap=None)

Comment: Can you edit your post above to include `.head()` of your gdf? If you are using recent geopandas, this should work. `c` is not managed by geopandas but passed to matplotlib. `color` is managed by geopandas and in this case should take care of color assignment.

Comment: hi @martinfleis I have added a snip of the dataframe head. Thanks for your help/ time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use GeoPandas 0.6.3 or 0.7.0 ideally. Then you should be able to pass your `colour` column into `color` keyword during plotting and geopandas should map colours assigned to each row to its geometry. See the following snippet illustrating the behaviour:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

g = [Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(1,1), Point(0.5, .5)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=g)
gdf['colour'] = ['#0000ff', 'r', '#0000ff', 'k']
gdf.plot(color=gdf.colour)
```

[image: resulting plot]

In your case, this should do the trick:

```
stores.plot(ax=ax, figsize=(40,10), color=stores['colour'])
```

If it does not, than you are either using old version of geopandas or there is a bug. In that case, please [report it](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues).